# CSS animation not in 60FPS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, transform

I have read few blogs on how to achieve smooth CSS animation, e.g [here](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108).

I'm literally trying to achieve red circle scale animation similar to below:

[image]

But the animation is not as smooth as I want it.

Here's my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tw4a3zd/2/)

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle .first,
.circle .second {
  width: 2200px;
  height: 2200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle .first {
  animation: scale 2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.01, 0, 0.08) infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

.circle .second {
  animation: scale-second 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.01, 0, 0.08) infinite;
  animation-delay: 7s;
  opacity: 0
}

@keyframes scale {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-second {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circle">
    <svg class="first" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="#ff948d">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
    </svg>

    <svg class="second" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="white">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can see that the animation is not smooth when you make the screen full size.

Comment: Hi do you have any URL to the base animation?

Comment: You mean the gif attached? @t3__rry

Comment: Yep this one. By the way you could start by adding a `will-change: transform` rule to `.circle` for it to be GPU accelerated https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/

Answer (score 1):

You might instead like to consider CSS transitions of transforms. These have the potential to render more smoothly as the browser does not have to calculate the frames between the key-frames specified.

One of the drawbacks is that the transition has to be triggered by an event - in this case on page load the class 'loaded' is added to each circle.

```js
document.body.onload = _ =>
  document.querySelectorAll('.circle').forEach(e => {
    e.classList.add('loaded')
  })


// handle the resize for this demo
document.body.onresize = _ => {
  console.log('Demo Resized - Resetting the Transition')
  // remove the class
  document.querySelectorAll('.circle').forEach(e => {
    e.classList.remove('loaded')
  })
  setTimeout(_ => {
    console.log('Transition Start');
    document.body.onload()
  }, 3000)
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.01, 0, 0.08), opacity 0s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.01, 0, 0.08), opacity 0s;
  -moz-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.01, 0, 0.08), opacity 0s;
  -o-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.01, 0, 0.08), opacity 0s;
}

.circle.first {
  background: #ff948d;
}

.circle.second {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

.circle.loaded {
  transform: scale(100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(100);
  -moz-transform: scale(100);
  -o-transform: scale(100);
  -ms-transform: scale(100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circle first"></div>
  <div class="circle second"></div>
</body>
```